# DC Motor only works with programmer

Tags: dc-motor

I have designed a micro controller circuit to actuate a DC motor using signals from an ATmega234P chip via a L239DNE H-Bridge. The problem I am having is that the motor runs slower than usual while executing the PWM code. As soon as I connect an MKII programmer to the ISP the motor works properly. Attached are my circuit schematics and the code that I am running. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Code ([source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N9SsPWBI0UgqDbr0tBobbDUwlEQQdsx8/view?usp=sharing)):

```
/*
 * DCM_PWM.c
 *
 * Created: 14/09/2018 6:31:42 PM
 * Author : s4354441
 */ 

#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void setup_timer0 (void)
{
  DDRB = (1<<DDB3) | (1<<DDB4); // set the PWM pin to output.
  TCCR0A = (1<<COM0A1) | (1<<COM0A0) | (1<<COM0B1) | (1<<COM0B0) | (0<WGM01) | (1<<WGM00); // toggle OC0A on compare match
  TCCR0B = (0<<WGM02) | (0<<CS02)| (0<<CS01) | (1<<CS00); //select PWM, Phase Correct
  OCR0A = 0; // set output compare value
  OCR0B = 0; // set output compare value
}

void PWM_func (void)
{
  for (int i=0; i<255; i++) {
    OCR0A = i;
    _delay_ms(25);
  }

  for (int i=255; i>0; i--) {
    OCR0A = i;
    _delay_ms(10);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<255; i++) {
    OCR0B = i;
    _delay_ms(5);
  }

  for (int i=255; i>0; i--) {
    OCR0B = i;
    _delay_ms(25);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<255; i++) {
    OCR0A = i;
    _delay_ms(10);
  }
}


int main (void)
{   
  setup_timer0();
  PWM_func();
}
```

[PCB Schematic 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKpg1Jt21Sw6Cz7IPf7SAHh9MRWIcAi5/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

[PCB Schematic 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rkh9cKadHAc9cjmebqvoJ9a3JGx0fYW8/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

Comment: In your CPU schematic, it would seem to me that the positions of L1 and C2 need to be swapped. I'm not sure what portions of the chip are disabled when AVCC is grounded -- this may or may not have any bearing on your problem.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I doubt that would change what happens when the programmer is plugged in.  It is wrong, mind you, and should still be fixed.

Comment: @rsdanam: Motors do incredibly ugly things to power rails.  If you're running your motor and your microprocessor off of the same supply, then it's a surprise that it works even *with* the programmer.  If you're running the micro off of a supply that's derived from the motor supply then give us schematics to how you're doing that -- sufficiently dirty power to a regulator will come out dirty on the other end.

Comment: @rsdanam: Do you have an oscilloscope with which you can look at the microprocessor's power supply rail, and the PWM going to the motor?  There's a lot of possible problems here which could be eliminated by poking around with even a cheap scope.

Comment: @TimWescott: The 5V power is derived from the 12V power, as shown on the second schematic. It's true that plugging in the programmer could be helping to stabilize the 5V power rail.

Answer (score 2):

It would not run at all with the schematic as shown,. So L1C2 must be reversed on the schematic.

But servo motors demand heavy current only during position command changes, (which in this case may be >> 100mA ) so the low power L05 regulator is possibly suffering from overload while the voltage drops to limit the current.

Make sure you scope the voltage and ensure this is not the problem.  The LC values are not ideal as a low pass filter breakpoint and more filtering and care with analog ground not sharing motor current is essential.

In short, no pun intended, without reviewing your code, you seem to be having power supply issues and no report of servo surge current specs.

Try a PC PSU until you learn how to specify and choose a better supply.

Comment: The question is not about a position commanded servomotor but about a DC motor driven by a notorious Darlington bridge.